# My dog keeps catching on fire, what should I do?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, mods

[image: Hot Dog]

My dogs keep walking through fires and dying. Is there a mod that makes them try and avoid it, or put themselves out (by heading for water) when they're on fire? I've lost countless dogs like this.

Comment: Can you ask a question without it having an epic title?

Comment: Bwahahaha... oh dear... seriously, there needs to be a badge or something awarded for these question titles... and is it me or does the dog have a sad face on...? :/

Comment: You could carry a bucket of water for Dog-On-Fire Extinguishing Emergencies, or not have open flames just sitting around, waiting to be walked through.

Comment: Is that Trantorus? I never could get those dogs to move. At all.

Comment: Yes, were you on SMP? I've had reports of dog-related troubles in SMP.

Comment: @echoback But fires are *cool!*

Comment: No, I played it in singleplayer.

Comment: Screenshot is as epic as title.  The dog looks incredibly sad.  No pain ... just depression.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe not exactly what you were looking for, but there is [WolfSpawn](http://forums.bukkit.org/threads/mech-wolfspawn-0-42-make-pet-wolves-respawn-after-death-spawn-wolf-818.19693/) Plugin for Bukkit which will let the pet respawn after death.